# How to apply TOP statement to only 1 column while selecting multiple columns from a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to select multiple columns from a table, but I want to select top certain number of records based on one column. I tried this  :

```
select roll_no ,marks as Percentage
from database
where marks in (select top (3) *
                from database
                where subject = ''
                order by marks desc) order by percentage desc
```

and I am getting the error:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the
>   sub-query is not introduced with EXISTS or more than specified number
>   of records.

I also tried :

```
select roll_no ,marks as Percentage
from database
where marks in (select top (3) marks
                from database
                where subject = ''
                order by marks desc) order by percentage desc
```

which returns the right result for some subjects but for others..it is displaying top marks from other subjects as well.

eg :

```
+---------+-------+
| roll_no | marks |
+---------+-------+
|10003    |  87   | 
|10006    |  72   | 
|10003    |  72   |    
|10002    |  67   |     
|10004    |  67   |  
+---------+-------+
```

How to frame the query correctly?

sample data :

```
+---------+-------+---------+
| roll_no | marks |subject  |
+---------+-------+---------+
|10001    |  45   | Maths   |
|10001    |  72   | Science |
|10001    |  64   | English |     
|10002    |  52   | Maths   |        
|10002    |  35   | Science |   
|10002    |  75   | English |      
|10003    |  52   | Maths   |        
|10003    |  35   | Science |   
|10003    |  75   | English | 
|10004    |  52   | Maths   |        
|10004    |  35   | Science |   
|10004    |  75   | English |  
+---------+-------+---------+
```

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images.

Comment: Is the marks column unique?

Comment: That is valid syntax.  You have something else going on.

Comment: Thats what I fail to understand..for some subjects it works fine ..for others its pulling records of other subjects as well...and for some it is not giving the percentages in desc order...odd  it is

Comment: @AnitaMathew . . . You are confused.  I am confused.  Your question mentions a syntax error, which doesn't seem to appropriate.  Your comment mentions unexpected data.  Ask *another* question, provide sample data, desired results.  Explain what you want when there are ties in the data.

Comment: As paparazzo mentioned, the query you posted is valid syntactically and should not throw you the error you posted. Please review that either the query posted is the same you are executing, or the question isn't about the error mentioned.

Comment: select roll_no ,marks as Percentage from database where marks in (select top (3) * from from database where subject = ' ' order by marks desc) order by Percentage desc

Comment: @EzLo  I tried this variant of the query which was giving the mentioned error . The thing is it gives right result for some subjects. but for others it is pulling up top  percentages from the other subjects..eg : Roll_no   percentage
10004      81
10003 78
10004 78
10001  67
10001  67

Comment: @AnitaMathew What you need is to use a JOIN instead of using an IN filter. If you can explain exactly the logic behind retriving the values (the top 3 marks for any subject? for a specific subject? marks can repeat?, etc), we can generate a query for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm right and you are looking for the best 3 marks for each subject, then you can get it with the following:

```
DECLARE @SelectedSubject VARCHAR(50) = 'Maths'

;WITH FilteredSubjectMarks AS
(
    SELECT
        D.Subject,
        D.Roll_no,
        D.Marks,
        MarksRanking = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY D.Marks DESC)
    FROM
        [Database] AS D
    WHERE
        D.Subject = @SelectedSubject
)
SELECT
    F.*
FROM
    FilteredSubjectMarks AS F
WHERE
    F.MarksRanking <= 3
```

Comment: Thanks.. that helps..But I have a dropdown from which the subject is selected and the top 3 of the corresponding subject are populated in a chart ..So I just need the code to return 3 records for the selected subject..Your code which is correct gives top 3 of all subjects.

Comment: @AnitaMathew i've edited the query to use a filter by subject. Check now if it's ok for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions to rank your `marks` column (specifically `dense_rank`, which allows duplicate rankings whilst retaining sequential numbering) and then return all rows with a rank of `3` or less:

```
declare @t table(roll_no int identity(1,1),marks int);
insert into @t(marks) values(2),(4),(5),(8),(6),(1),(3),(2),(1),(8);

with t as
(
    select roll_no
            ,marks
            ,dense_rank() over (order by marks desc) as r
    from @t
)
select *
from t
where r <= 3;
```

Output:

```
+---------+-------+---+
| roll_no | marks | r |
+---------+-------+---+
|       4 |     8 | 1 |
|      10 |     6 | 1 |
|       5 |     6 | 2 |
|       3 |     5 | 3 |
+---------+-------+---+
```